# Autocomplete with case-sensitivity

Tags: autocomplete, primefaces

Please I have a big problem with case-sensitivity in the autocomplete primefaces.

For example let say my list has `Alcatel`, `ABost`

When I type `a`, `Alcatel1 is the only result of autocomplete

But when I type `A`, both `Alcatel` and `ABost` are shown.

> What should I do for autocomplete to list both the items in both the cases?

public List complete(String query) {

List results = new ArrayList();

```
    for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {  

        if(list.get(i).getNomFabricant().contains(query))
        results.add(list.get(i).getNomFabricant());  
    }  

    return results;  
}
```

Comment: Does an attribut exist for example to set a true for making him accept booth !!!!

Answer (score 0):

it is ok know Thx for your help in any way :)
this is the code

```
public List<String> complete(String query) {  
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();  

        for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {          
            if(list.get(i).getNomFabricant().toUpperCase().contains(query.toUpperCase()))
            results.add(list.get(i).getNomFabricant());  
        }  

        return results;  
    }
```